# Width of item in second series too wide

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to show 2 OHLCSeries in one chart/seriesCollection. The first series seems to be OK but in the secord there are item(s) with weird width. Look the pic:

[image]

Maybe the problem comes from count of item in series - 1st series has 20 items and the 2nd series just 1.

Here is the complete app code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickMarkPosition;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Minute;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeriesCollection;

public class sample8 {

    private ChartPanel chartPanel;
    private JFreeChart chart;
    private final OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();

    public sample8() {
        chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(null, "Time", "Price", seriesCollection, false);
        chart.getXYPlot().setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
        chart.setAntiAlias(false);

        // renderer
        CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(renderer);

        // Y-axis
        chart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
        NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false);

        // X-axis
        DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
        dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnit.MINUTE, 1), true, true);
        dateAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);

        // chartPanel
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.getChartRenderingInfo().setEntityCollection(null);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));

        // series
        addSeries1();
        addSeries2();
    }

    private void addSeries1() {
        OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("");
        series.add(new Minute(0, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.23D, 98.47D, 97.15D, 97.43);
        series.add(new Minute(1, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.47D, 98.81D, 96.27D, 97.49);
        series.add(new Minute(2, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.88D, 96.87D, 96.11D, 96.75);
        series.add(new Minute(3, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.05D, 96.94D, 95.89D, 96.59);
        series.add(new Minute(4, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.92D, 97.00D, 95.69D, 96.92);
        series.add(new Minute(5, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.34D, 96.71D, 95.68D, 96.70);
        series.add(new Minute(6, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.65D, 96.87D, 94.91D, 96.38);
        series.add(new Minute(7, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.75D, 98.20D, 96.90D, 97.24);
        series.add(new Minute(8, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.72D, 98.47D, 97.35D, 97.64);
        series.add(new Minute(9, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.30D, 98.77D, 97.56D, 97.99);
        series.add(new Minute(10, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 100.09D, 99.79D, 99.17D, 99.25);
        series.add(new Minute(11, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 100.39D, 100.24D, 99.66D, 100.13);
        series.add(new Minute(12, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.99D, 98.63D, 97.67D, 98.54);
        series.add(new Minute(13, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 99.33D, 99.37D, 97.96D, 98.34);
        series.add(new Minute(14, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.00D, 98.16D, 97.17D, 97.52);
        series.add(new Minute(15, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.77D, 97.92D, 97.37D, 97.70);
        series.add(new Minute(16, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.33D, 97.94D, 97.15D, 97.67);
        series.add(new Minute(17, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 99.59D, 98.33D, 97.89D, 98.22);
        series.add(new Minute(18, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.67D, 97.09D, 95.66D, 97.07);
        series.add(new Minute(19, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.65D, 97.58D, 96.79D, 97.00);
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    private void addSeries2() {
        OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("");
        series.add(new Minute(0, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96D, 96.5D, 95.5D, 96.2D);
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    public ChartPanel getChartPanel() {
        return chartPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sample8 app = new sample8();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("sample8");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(app.getChartPanel());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Why JFreeChart doesn't set width of items automatically the same for all?**

Comment: OT: `DateTickUnit` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to experiment with [`setAutoWidthMethod()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.html#setAutoWidthMethod-int-) and `WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST`. Two items appear to be a minimum; five are shown below in series "Two".

```
CandlestickRenderer r = (CandlestickRenderer) chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
r.setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);
```

[image]

In addition,

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch threa](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)d.
- Don't use `setPreferredSize()` when you really mean to override `getPreferredSize()`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586415/width-of-item-in-second-series-too-wide#comment43626390_27586415), `DateTickUnit` is deprecated; use `DateTickUnitType` instead.

As tested:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickMarkPosition;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTickUnitType;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Minute;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeriesCollection;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513 */
public class Sample8 {

    private final ChartPanel chartPanel;
    private final OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();

    public Sample8() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(
                "Sample8", "Time", "Price", seriesCollection, true);
        chart.getXYPlot().setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
        CandlestickRenderer r = (CandlestickRenderer) chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
        r.setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);

        // Y-axis
        NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false);

        // X-axis
        DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
        dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE, 1));
        dateAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);

        // chartPanel
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 400);
            }
        };

        // series
        addSeries1();
        addSeries2();
    }

    private void addSeries1() {
        OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("One");
        series.add(new Minute(0, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.23D, 98.47D, 97.15D, 97.43);
        series.add(new Minute(1, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.47D, 98.81D, 96.27D, 97.49);
        series.add(new Minute(2, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.88D, 96.87D, 96.11D, 96.75);
        series.add(new Minute(3, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.05D, 96.94D, 95.89D, 96.59);
        series.add(new Minute(4, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.92D, 97.00D, 95.69D, 96.92);
        series.add(new Minute(5, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.34D, 96.71D, 95.68D, 96.70);
        series.add(new Minute(6, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.65D, 96.87D, 94.91D, 96.38);
        series.add(new Minute(7, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.75D, 98.20D, 96.90D, 97.24);
        series.add(new Minute(8, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.72D, 98.47D, 97.35D, 97.64);
        series.add(new Minute(9, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.30D, 98.77D, 97.56D, 97.99);
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    private void addSeries2() {
        OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("Two");
        series.add(new Minute(0, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96D, 96.5D, 95.5D, 96.2D);
        series.add(new Minute(1, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 100.39D, 100.24D, 99.66D, 100.13);
        series.add(new Minute(2, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.99D, 98.63D, 97.67D, 98.54);
        series.add(new Minute(3, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 99.33D, 99.37D, 97.96D, 98.34);
        series.add(new Minute(4, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.00D, 98.16D, 97.17D, 97.52);
//        series.add(new Minute(5, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.77D, 97.92D, 97.37D, 97.70);
//        series.add(new Minute(6, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.33D, 97.94D, 97.15D, 97.67);
//        series.add(new Minute(7, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 99.59D, 98.33D, 97.89D, 98.22);
//        series.add(new Minute(8, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.67D, 97.09D, 95.66D, 97.07);
//        series.add(new Minute(9, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.65D, 97.58D, 96.79D, 97.00);
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    public ChartPanel getChartPanel() {
        return chartPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Sample8 app = new Sample8();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(app.getChartPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thanks for really complex answer. As you mentioned that 2 items are required minimum to auto-calculate the width, do you think is it possible to set the width manually? Because in this case I really need to show just 1 item in serie.

Comment: Oh I just found setCandleWidth method - http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/CandlestickRenderer.html#setCandleWidth-double-

Comment: This would make a useful [answer to your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).