# Auto range on range axis on zoom

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a candlestick chart, which user can zoom and pan, exacly like this [TradingView chart](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ:AAPL).

```
// Domain axis
DateAxis dateAxis = new DateAxis();

// Range axis
NumberAxis priceAxis = new NumberAxis("Price");
priceAxis.setRangeType(RangeType.POSITIVE);
priceAxis.setAutoRange(true);
priceAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

// Plot
CandlestickRenderer renderer = new CandlestickRenderer();
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(mPriceDataSet, dateAxis, priceAxis, renderer);
plot.setDomainPannable(true);
plot.setRangePannable(false);

// Chart
mChart = new JFreeChart("Price History", plot);
```

which `mPriceDataSet` is my data set and is of type `DefaultOHLCDataset`. And here is how I create the `ChartPanel`:

```
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(mChart);
chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true);
chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(false);
chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
```

**Behavior:** When the chart is rendered everything is okay, however when user zooms and/or pans the view port, the range axis doesn't scale and shows the very first range.

**Desired Behavior:** While zooming/panning range axis should dynamically set its range. Exactly like [TrandingView charts](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NASDAQ:AAPL).

---

## MCVE

I've created an MCVE based on your [Sample8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/1841194). To reproduce the problem, just run the app and select the candle at 12:5 using mouse dragging. As you can see, the chart after zoom/selection will not be auto ranged and user has to manually do so using the context menu.

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.CandlestickRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.time.Minute;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.ohlc.OHLCSeriesCollection;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class AutoRangeTestApp {

    private final ChartPanel chartPanel;
    private final OHLCSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new OHLCSeriesCollection();

    public AutoRangeTestApp() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(
                "Sample8", "Time", "Price", seriesCollection, true);
        chart.getXYPlot().setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
        chart.getXYPlot().setDomainPannable(true);
        CandlestickRenderer r = (CandlestickRenderer) chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
        r.setAutoWidthMethod(CandlestickRenderer.WIDTHMETHOD_SMALLEST);

        // Y-axis
        NumberAxis numberAxis = (NumberAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        numberAxis.setAutoRangeStickyZero(false);

        // X-axis
        DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis();
        dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"));
        dateAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.MINUTE, 1));
        dateAxis.setTickMarkPosition(DateTickMarkPosition.MIDDLE);

        // chartPanel
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(800, 400);
            }
        };
        chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true);
        chartPanel.setRangeZoomable(false);

        // series
        addSeries1();
    }

    private void addSeries1() {
        OHLCSeries series = new OHLCSeries("One");
        series.add(new Minute(0, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.23D, 98.47D, 97.15D, 97.43);
        series.add(new Minute(1, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.47D, 98.81D, 96.27D, 97.49);
        series.add(new Minute(2, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.88D, 96.87D, 96.11D, 96.75);
        series.add(new Minute(3, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.05D, 96.94D, 95.89D, 96.59);
        series.add(new Minute(4, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 95.92D, 97.00D, 95.69D, 96.92);
        series.add(new Minute(5, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.34D, 96.71D, 95.68D, 96.70);
        series.add(new Minute(6, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 96.65D, 96.87D, 94.91D, 96.38);
        series.add(new Minute(7, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.75D, 98.20D, 96.90D, 97.24);
        series.add(new Minute(8, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 97.72D, 98.47D, 97.35D, 97.64);
        series.add(new Minute(9, 12, 1, 1, 2014), 98.30D, 98.77D, 97.56D, 97.99);
        seriesCollection.addSeries(series);
    }

    public ChartPanel getChartPanel() {
        return chartPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                AutoRangeTestApp app = new AutoRangeTestApp();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(app.getChartPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513), I can't reproduce this with JFreeChart 1.5. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod I also tested with version 1.5, the same behavior. When I pans the chart using ctrl + drag, auto ranging on Y axis does not work and I have to manually auto range it using `ChartPanel`'s context menu.

Comment: I use option-drag on Mac, but I don't see anything unexpected with [`Sample8`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513) or the demo; can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @trashgod I've added a MCVE to my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything untoward on Mac 1.8.0_201, Java 1.8.0_201, JFreeChart 1.5. If I inadvertently mouse-wheel zoom as I drag, the  new zoom takes effect, and I can auto range using either the context menu or the drag-left mouse gesture

Comment: @trashgod Zoom functionality is okay. I've no problem with. I just want to when zoom takes effect, auto range function automatically run. i.e. not having the user to manually auto range through context menu.

Comment: Maybe [`restoreAutoBounds()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513) on `mouseReleased()`?

Comment: @trashgod I just tested `restoreAutoBounds()`. It resets the zoom, however I need to preserve the zoom and auto range the portion of data that is visible.

Comment: Sadly, I'm nonplussed; at any given zoom level, I see the domain range adjusting continually and correctly as I option-drag; new domain _ticks_ scroll into view on one end as old ones disappear on the other. To see new _data_ scroll into view, you may want to look at [`SlidingXYDataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20slidingxydataset).