# Annotations on candlestick chart not working

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to add annotations to a chart. It seems like it's added, since the `size()` of the plot's annotations list increases if I add one more. The problem is that it's not being displayed.

```
OHLCDataset candles = createCandleDataset();

// Create chart
chart = ChartFactory.createCandlestickChart(
    "mychart", "", "", candles, true);

XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();        

XYShapeAnnotation a1 = new XYShapeAnnotation(
    new Rectangle2D.Double(10.0, 20.0, 20.0, 30.0),
    new BasicStroke(1.0f), Color.blue);
plot.addAnnotation(a1);

ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
setContentPane(panel);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`XYShapeAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYShapeAnnotation.html) API says:

> The shape coordinates are specified in data space.

The coordinates of your `Rectangle2D` may be inapparent relative to your actual data. Instead, use coordinates from your [`OHLCDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/OHLCDataset.html) to construct your annotation. Focusing on the second item in `series1` in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513), the chart below illustrates retrieving data from the underlying `OHLCSeries` to create an annotation one period wide and spanning the high/low value.

```
// series
addSeries1();
OHLCSeries series = seriesCollection.getSeries(0);
OHLCItem item = (OHLCItem) series.getDataItem(1);
RegularTimePeriod t = item.getPeriod();
long x = t.getFirstMillisecond();
long w = t.getLastMillisecond() - t.getFirstMillisecond(); 
double y = item.getLowValue();
double h = item.getHighValue() - y;
XYShapeAnnotation a1 = new XYShapeAnnotation(
    new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h),
    new BasicStroke(1f), Color.blue
);
chart.getXYPlot().addAnnotation(a1);
```

[image]

Other implementations of [`OHLCDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/OHLCDataset.html) have corresponding accessors.

Comment: Ok I was assuming that coordinates (0, 0) would be top left corner on the plot... I will try your code out!

Comment: Oh I see.. the Y-coordinate is `price` and the X-coordinate is in `milliseconds`. So since I use daily chart, my X-values are LARGE, like `3600 * 1000 * 24`

Comment: @BakedInhalf: Exactly; I've updated the fragment to use the target item's period.