# JFreeChart: how to move Y-axis from left to right hand side?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

I use JFreeChart to create a candlestick chart. The horizontal axis is a DateAxis to indicate the time, the vertical axis is a NumberAxis, to indicate the price. As the screenshot shows, is the price axis shown on the left hand side of the chart.
[image: Candlestick chart, price values on left hand side]

I would like the vertical axis to be displayed on the right hand side of the chart, instead of the left hand side. I have been looking in the class overview for NumberAxis, ValueAxis and Axis classes in JFreeChart but could not find a method which can make this modification.
Can somebody please show me how to make this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13362809/230513), you can use the [`XYPlot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) method [`setRangeAxisLocation()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html#setRangeAxisLocation-org.jfree.chart.axis.AxisLocation-) to set the location of the primary range axis. The image below illustrates the effect of the following addition to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611246/230513):

```
chart.getXYPlot().setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.TOP_OR_RIGHT);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer trashgod. This solves the issue. It also shows that I was thinking in the wrong direction. I assumed that the Axis determines where it will be located. This is not correct: the Plot determines where the Axis will be positioned.

Comment: @Joe: Good insight. Visually, the plot aggregates the axes and renderer(s).