# How to rotate x-axis labels on JFreeChart xyPlot

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to display the x-axis labels at a 45 degree angle, similar to this

[image]

The examples I've found all assume that getDomainAxis() returns a CategoryAxis, which has a setCategoryLabelPositions() method.  But in an XY Plot, I get a ValueAxis.  There's a method for displaying the labels vertical, but not rotating at an arbitrary angle.

## Update

Looking at the code for `ValueAxis.drawTickMarksAndLabels()`, there does seem to be mention of an angle on the `ValueTick` object, but I'm not sure how to get access to that or where to set it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had previously thought that [`ValueAxis`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html) tick label orientation was limited by `setVerticalTickLabels()`. In this [discussion](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/discussions/372), you cite a forum [topic](https://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25189) that suggests a potential workaround.

As a proof of concept, based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086403/230513), the variation below illustrates the approach using a custom implementation of `refreshTicksHorizontal()`. Note:

- The use of `setVerticalTickLabels(true)` prompts the axis to reserve space for the labels.
- For expedience, the rotation angle is hard-coded; it should probably be made a constructor parameter.
- The approach was only tested with horizontal orientation.
- As the chart theme had already been applied in the `ChartFactory`, the example uses an `AttributedString` to decorate the axis label.

[image: Rotated Axis labels]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.DateTick;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.Tick;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.ui.RectangleEdge;
import org.jfree.data.time.Minute;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries;
import org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76574565/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70071299/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513
 */
public class TimeTest {

    private static XYDataset createDataset() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
        series.add(new Minute(f.parse("Sat Nov 20 12:10:00 PST 2021")), 72.5);
        series.add(new Minute(f.parse("Sat Nov 20 13:11:00 PST 2021")), 70.7);
        series.add(new Minute(f.parse("Sat Nov 20 14:12:00 PST 2021")), 70.1);
        return new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart
(            "Test", "Time", "Temperture °F", dataset, true, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer r = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        r.setDefaultShapesVisible(true);
        DateAxis domain = new DateAxis() {
            //@see https://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25189
            //todo paramterize angle
            @Override
            protected List refreshTicksHorizontal(Graphics2D g2, Rectangle2D dataArea, RectangleEdge edge) {
                List ticks = super.refreshTicksHorizontal(g2, dataArea, edge);
                List ret = new ArrayList();
                for (Tick tick : (List<Tick>) ticks) {
                    if (tick instanceof DateTick dateTick) {
                        ret.add(new DateTick(dateTick.getDate(), dateTick.getText(),
                            dateTick.getTextAnchor(), dateTick.getRotationAnchor(), -45));
                    } else {
                        ret.add(tick);
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }
        };
        AttributedString as = new AttributedString("TimeN");
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, 16, 0, 5);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.WEIGHT, TextAttribute.WEIGHT_BOLD, 0, 5);
        as.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUB, 4, 5);
        domain.setAttributedLabel(as);
        domain.setDateFormatOverride(f);
        domain.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
        plot.setDomainAxis(domain);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 250);
            }
        };
        f.add(chartPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  What is the purpose of `setDefaultShapesVisible()`?  That doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Thank you for identifying this approach. Sorry, I can't reproduce your finding concerning shape visibility. The [`ChartFactory`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/b9a36f260cd243ddea6cbfd603f6db32dcf7565f/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1805) sets the `shapes` parameter to `false`.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it.   Not sure what I was seeing.  I actually want shapes to be off, so I set it to false